# how to remove background lights from reflective surfaces?

Tags: lighting

I made a red ball with black background

[image]

There are background lights reflected from surfaces

[image]

I want to remove background lights from surfaces

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you expand a bit more on that? As in, what's your end goal, what's the effect you're going for? Because if you remove glossy reflection, the sphere will not look as a reflective surface - which may be what you're after, but it's unclear from your question. What you see there is actually a the reflection of the black box that surrounds the sphere - the bright part is the opening, so it's the reflection of the "sky". Are you just trying to make the box invisible in the reflection, or are you after something else?

Answer (score 3):

In the panel on the right (in your top image) there is a setting called "Ray Visibility - Click to expand the section, then un-check "Glossy"

[image: Tay]

Answer (score 2):

You could lower down the *Specular* value of the ball material (and also increase its *Roughness*):

[image]